# Mapstruct: Can't generate mapping method from iterable to non-iterable type

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have following class structure:

`SOURCE`

```
class c1 {
  List<c11> o1;
}
class c11 {
 List<c12> o2
}
```

`TARGET`

```
class c1 {
  List<c11> o1;
}
class c11 {
 c12 o2
}
```

Here is mapper class:

```
@Mapper
class MyMapper {
 c12 map(List<c12> o);
}
```

I get error: `Can't generate mapping method from iterable to non-iterable type.`

Now to solve this i am doing this:

```
default c12 map(List<c12> o) {
  return o.get(0);
}
```

even then i am getting this error
`can't map property List<c12> o1[].o2 to List<c12> o1[].o2. consider to declare/implement a mapping methos: c12 map(List<c12> value)`

Comment: Your example looks to be incomplete. c12 is never defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mapstruct map iterable to non iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341245/mapstruct-map-iterable-to-non-iterable)