# MapStruct List<String> to Single Object with Nested List of Objects

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I'm trying to convert a `List<String>` to the below DomainUpdate object. The DomainUpdate object contains a List of Domains and a Domain just have a String value.

```
DomainUpdate{
    List<Domain> domains;
}

Domain{
    String value;
}
```

I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to do this and my current implementation just complains:
`error: Can't generate mapping method from iterable type from java stdlib to non-iterable type.`

**Mapper**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED)
public interface DomainProtobufMapper {
    DomainUpdate domainsToProtobuf(List<String> domains);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly match this but let's create your custom method with the return type you want and the argument you need to convert.

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default DomainUpdate domainsToProtobuf(List<String> values) {
        DomainUpdate domainUpdate = new DomainUpdate();
        domainUpdate.setDomains(valueToDomain(values));
        return domainUpdate;
    }

    Domain valueToDomain(String value);
    List<Domain> valueToDomain(List<String> values);
}
```

`OR`

You can do it with a dummy parameter like [in this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860689/2039546)

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default DomainUpdate domainsToProtobuf(List<String> values) {
        return domainsToProtobuf(null, values);
    }

    @Mapping(target = "domains", source = "values")
    DomainUpdate domainsToProtobuf(Integer dummy, List<String> values);

    Domain valueToDomain(String value);
    List<Domain> valueToDomain(List<String> values);
}
```

Checkout [this](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Why-is-it-not-possible-for-MapStruct-to-generate-implementations-for-Iterable-Stream-and-Map-Types-from-update-MappingTarget-methods) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: thank you Ismail! This is what I was looking for. Do you have any opinions on preference of approach?